# laser_assembler generates empty data

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, guys

I'm trying to assemble the laser lines into a big pointcloud2.

First I transformed the laser data into pointCloud2, which can be seen in rviz. But after assembling, no data is published. I have also modified the launch file. Please help me.

```
// Create a publisher for the clouds that we assemble
pubAssembledPointCloud2 = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> (assemPC2Topic, 1);

// Assemble the pointcloud2 from laser
ros::service::waitForService("assemble_scans2");
// Create the service client for calling the assembler
client = nh.serviceClient<AssembleScans2> ("assemble_scans2");

firstTime = true;
while(ros::ok()) {   
      
    // Start the timer that will trigger the processing loop (timerCallback)
    timer = nh.createTimer(ros::Duration(8.0), &LaserCloud::timerCallback, this);
    ros::spin();
}
```

---

```
AssembleScans2 srv;
srv.request.begin = e.last_real;
srv.request.end = e.current_real;

if(client.call(srv)) {
    pubAssembledPointCloud2.publish(srv.response.cloud);
    ROS_INFO("Published pointcloud2 with %u points", (uint32_t)(srv.response.cloud.height*srv.response.cloud.width));
}
else {
    ROS_ERROR("Error making service call\n");
}
```

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/134881/laser_assembler-generates-empty-data/) by [levi](https://answers.ros.org/users/12701/levi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is

```
git clone https://github.com/ros-perception/laser_assembler.git
```

What you mean - i.e get a local copy of the laser_assembler code base?

Mark

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2014-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [levi](https://answers.ros.org/users/12701/levi/) on 2014-03-02**:
Thank you. I'm quite new to ROS so some silly questions:

1. In what directory to git clone?
2. After git clone, what's next?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-03-03**:
You would put that in your workspace. However if you are using ubuntu laser-assembler is released as a debian package, so unless you want to modify that code, just install it via apt-get.

**Comment by [levi](https://answers.ros.org/users/12701/levi/) on 2014-03-04**:
thank you. I can use it now. But I it publish the empty list after assembling